# How to get current state of MatSelect element (Multiselect) in angular material

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material-5

I am using MatSelect with a multi-select option. On every element check or uncheck there is a typescript function which will be called every time so the problem is, I am not able to differentiate which click event is populated from UI for ex. Apple checked then call API and if Apple unchecked then do nothing

.html file

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected" formControlName="tagList" id="tagList" placeholder="Select Tag" name="tagList" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of tagList" [value]="tag" 
         (click)="isSelectedTagIsCallback(tag, $event.value)">
         {{tag.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

.ts file

```
isSelectedTagIsCallback(data, event) {
      if(checked){
         // Call API
      }
     else{
       // Do nothing
     }
}
```

Is above approach is wrong or right? If right then how do I get that checked/ Unchecked event or flag to call an API on the basis of value

Comment: What does not work of you current approach?

Comment: Every time isSelectedTagIsCallback method call that is fine but in that method I have to check for multi-select element is checked or unchecked

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't need to pass option value into function:
In your typescript like this:

```
selected: any = '';
isSelectedTagIsCallback() {
    if(this.selected!=''){
       alert(this.selected); //CALL API Here
    }else{
       // Do nothing
}
```

In your html as you posted replace `isSelectedTagIsCallback(tag, $event.value)` to `isSelectedTagIsCallback()` In function you can get multiple checkbox value separated by comma.

here is working example: [angular-multiple-value-selected-in-material](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7uxs2)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: The selected is list of selected tags

Comment: yes, there you can get the value of which is selected or checked items only.

Comment: Then I need to iterate over an array and check for a condition is it like that?

Comment: can you tell me what type of condition you want to check there ??

Comment: Just want to check if the current value is present in the list (after API call). I have tried let me check is it working good for all case

Comment: As per business requirement I need to handle more that 3 condition and use cases

Comment: By doing comparison in between current value and API call value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171537/discussion-between-prashant-pimpale-and-sanoj-v).

Comment: If the user checks the checkbox only after my method will execute otherwise do nothing --> Do nothing on uncheck

Comment: Ok, but you can not get the uncheck checkbox value So how will you check  condition?

Comment: In my code function called isSelectedTagIsCallback which takes an input of tag so that is coming in every click (On check and On uncheck) which I don't want.

Comment: Ok. check the current  `tag` value present in `selected` list  or you can use filter, If present then call api else do nothing

Comment: Yes that is what I have tried but for not working in one case

Comment: Are you sure this `isSelectedTagIsCallback(tag, $event.value)` get a tag value.

Comment: Yes absolutely!

Comment: Let me explain-> There are 4 option like 1) Callback 2) General 3) API response1 4) API response2 in the ddl on a check I want to takes tag name from tag data after that there are three conditions,
1) tag name is equal to callback --> Callback
2) If no then tag name exists in API data list -->API response1, API response2
3) And none of above --> General

For point 1 and 2 it gives me a date in return and for 3rd No date